# Eliminating duplicate entries from TreeMap<Integer, Object[]> Object array values

Tags: java, dictionary, duplicates, treemap

//Bold values need to be validated to chk the duplicate entries from treemap object array.

Map<'Integer, Object[]> totalData = new TreeMap<'Integer, Object[]>();

totalData.put(1, new Object[] { 1, "2020-01-02T09:00:35.815", "00102464071240001", "29810441", "Success" });
totalData.put(2, new Object[] { 2, "2020-01-02T09:00:35.816", **"00102464071240002"**, **"29810442"**, **"Failure"** });
totalData.put(3, new Object[] { 3, "2020-01-02T09:00:35.817", "00102464071240003", "29810443", "Failure" });
totalData.put(4, new Object[] { 4, "2020-01-02T09:00:35.818", "00102464071240004", "29810444", "Success" });
totalData.put(5, new Object[] { 5, "2020-01-02T09:00:35.819", **"00102464071240002"**, **"29810442"**, **"Success"** });
totalData.put(6, new Object[] { 6, "2020-01-02T09:00:35.819", "00102464071240006", "29810446", "Failure" });
totalData.put(7, new Object[] { 7, "2020-01-02T09:00:35.820", **"00102464071240009"**, **"29810449"**, **"Success"** });  
totalData.put(8, new Object[] { 8, "2020-01-02T09:00:35.821", "00102464071240008", "29810448", "Success" });
totalData.put(9, new Object[] { 9, "2020-01-02T09:00:35.822", **"00102464071240009"**, **"29810449"**, **"Failure"** }); 

Final totalData object needs to be checked for duplicate entries. Bold entries are duplicated here, 

Excepted output should be (after eliminating duplicate entries):

totalData.put(1, new Object[] { 1, "2020-01-02T09:00:35.815", "00102464071240001", "29810441", "Success" });
totalData.put(3, new Object[] { 3, "2020-01-02T09:00:35.817", "00102464071240003", "29810443", "Failure" });
totalData.put(4, new Object[] { 4, "2020-01-02T09:00:35.818", "00102464071240004", "29810444", "Success" });
totalData.put(5, new Object[] { 5, "2020-01-02T09:00:35.819", "00102464071240002", "29810442", "Success" });
totalData.put(6, new Object[] { 6, "2020-01-02T09:00:35.819", "00102464071240006", "29810446", "Failure" });
totalData.put(7, new Object[] { 7, "2020-01-02T09:00:35.820", "00102464071240009", "29810449", "Success" });  
totalData.put(8, new Object[] { 8, "2020-01-02T09:00:35.821", "00102464071240008", "29810448", "Success" });

Please let us know your suggestion or idea to get this output

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, Object[]> totalData = new TreeMap<String, Object[]>();
totalData.put("00102464071240001-29810441", new Object[] { 1, "2020-01-02T09:00:35.815", "00102464071240001", "29810441", "Success" });
totalData.put("00102464071240002-29810442", new Object[] { 2, "2020-01-02T09:00:35.816", "00102464071240002", "29810442", "Failure" });
totalData.put("00102464071240003-29810443", new Object[] { 3, "2020-01-02T09:00:35.817", "00102464071240003", "29810443", "Failure" });
totalData.put("00102464071240004-29810444", new Object[] { 4, "2020-01-02T09:00:35.818", "00102464071240004", "29810444", "Success" });
totalData.put("00102464071240002-29810442", new Object[] { 5, "2020-01-02T09:00:35.819", "00102464071240002", "29810442", "Success" });
...
```

Basically make the combo of 2 values as a key to this map, since it can't take in duplicate keys, should give you unique entries when printed.